Android-MVI CoroutineFlow why this project use filterIsInstance instead of when?
https://github.com/Kotlin-Android-Open-Source/MVI-Coroutines-Flow
I saw a project on Git,
In MainVM, filterInstace is merge and used instead of the when as follows.
private fun SharedFlow<ViewIntent>.toPartialStateChangeFlow(): Flow<PartialStateChange> =
    merge(
      // users change
      merge(
        filterIsInstance<ViewIntent.Initial>(),
        filterIsInstance<ViewIntent.Retry>()
          .filter { viewState.value.error != null },
      ).toUserChangeFlow(),
      // refresh change
      filterIsInstance<ViewIntent.Refresh>()
        .toRefreshChangeFlow(),
      // remove user change
      filterIsInstance<ViewIntent.RemoveUser>()
        .toRemoveUserChangeFlow(),
    )

  private fun SharedFlow<ViewIntent>.toPartialStateChangeFlow(): Flow<PartialStateChange> =
    flatMapLatest { intent ->
      when (intent) {
        is ViewIntent.Initial || (ViewIntent.Retry && filter { viewState.value.error != null })
        -> toUserChangeFlow()
        is ViewIntent.Refresh -> toRefreshChangeFlow()
        is ViewIntent.RemoveUser -> toRemoveUserChangeFlow()
        else -> Unit
      }
    }

May I know why they used filterIsInstance and not a when?
I don't know the merits of expressing it that way.
